# How to write a foreach loop in PHP that can count the values of an XML element with a different element?

Tags: php, xml

My goal is to write a foreach loop in PHP that can search the food `name` (i.e. Chicken Pot Pie) with lowest `id` value (i.e. 5188) in `menu` and finds how many times the food has been served in a week. For example, the code should echos the result as follows:

1. Chicken Pot Pie: 3 times

2. Tournedos Rossini: 1 times

3. Beefsteak: 1 times

4. Tavern Sandwich: 0 times

5. Fish&Chips: 2 times

Note that XML data looks like below:

```
<foods total="5">
  <food>
    <id>5188</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Chicken Pot Pie</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5189</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Tournedos Rossini</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5190</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Beefsteak</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5191</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Tavern Sandwich</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5192</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Fish&amp;Chips</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
</foods>

<weekdays total="7">
  <day>
    <date>01-16-2016</date>
    <menu>We have served Beefsteak for today.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-17-2016</date>
    <menu>We have served Fish&amp;Chips for today.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-18-2016</date>
    <menu>Today, there is Chicken Pot Pie for you.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-19-2016</date>
    <menu>Fish&amp;Chips is one of the best foods in our restaurant</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-20-2016</date>
    <menu>Welcome home! Tournedos Rossini!</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-21-2016</date>
    <menu>Chicken Pot Pie</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-22-2016</date>
    <menu>Chicken Pot Pie is one of our most delicious dishes.</menu>
  </day>                        
</weekdays>
```

Comment: Why do you have :                                                                                   `<food>
    <id>5188</id>
    <food>
      <name>Chicken Pot Pie</name>
    </food>                                                                                                     </food>`,                                                                                                            It would be easier to process if the structure is like:                               `<food>
    <id>5188</id>
      <name>Chicken Pot Pie</name>
    </food>'`

Comment: @mikeO. please review the question, I changed the tag name ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily the lowest ID comes first, then totally in order up to the highest ID. This is in *document order* and SimpleXML XPath is in document order, so to have all names:

```
/*/food//name
```

Next to that you want to look in all the weekdays menu descriptions how often the term is used. For those you need all these texts to look into from the weekdays XML document:

```
/*/day/menu
```

In PHP code it's as simple as:

```
$foods    = simplexml_load_string($foodsBuffer);
$weekdays = simplexml_load_string($weekdaysBuffer);

$names = $foods->xpath('/*/food//name');
$menus = $weekdays->xpath('/*/day/menu');
```

Now you're concerned about looking into each name:

```
foreach ($names as $i => $name) {
    ...
}
```

This is probably the `foreach` you were looking for. However it's not yet complete, you need to check how often `$name` is part of the `$menus` entries.

This is text comparison and one library in PHP that is good with texts and compatible with UTF-8 used in SimpleXML is the PCRE library.

It has a handy function named [`preg_grep`](http://php.net/preg_grep) that can filter an array for matches:

```
$pattern = sprintf('/%s/u', preg_quote($name));
$result  = preg_grep($pattern, $menus);
```

This little piece of code creates the regex pattern and filters the array based on it. Take care if `$name` is empty, you'll get all hits. Just saying.

So the `foreach` in full would look like:

```
foreach ($names as $i => $name) {
    $pattern = sprintf('/%s/u', preg_quote($name));
    $result  = preg_grep($pattern, $menus);
    printf("%d.) %s: %d time(s)\n", $i + 1, $name, count($result));
}
```

And here is the examples output ([online demo](https://eval.in/303624)):

```
1.) Chicken Pot Pie: 3 time(s)
2.) Tournedos Rossini: 1 time(s)
3.) Beefsteak: 1 time(s)
4.) Tavern Sandwich: 0 time(s)
5.) Fish&Chips: 2 time(s)
```

So this answer demonstrates how you can bring multiple powerful cornerstones in PHP together: The XML parser, XPath queries, array-handling and regular expressions.

And the full example for completeness in this answer:

```
<?php
/**
 * How to write a foreach loop in PHP that can count the values of an XML element with a different element?
 * 
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/a/29219339/367456
 */


$foodsBuffer = <<<XML
<foods total="5">
  <food>
    <id>5188</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Chicken Pot Pie</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5189</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Tournedos Rossini</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5190</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Beefsteak</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5191</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Tavern Sandwich</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
  <food>
    <id>5192</id>
    <yourfood>
      <name>Fish&amp;Chips</name>
    </yourfood>
  </food>
</foods>
XML;

$weekdaysBuffer = <<<XML
<weekdays total="7">
  <day>
    <date>01-16-2016</date>
    <menu>We have served Beefsteak for today.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-17-2016</date>
    <menu>We have served Fish&amp;Chips for today.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-18-2016</date>
    <menu>Today, there is Chicken Pot Pie for you.</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-19-2016</date>
    <menu>Fish&amp;Chips is one of the best foods in our restaurant</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-20-2016</date>
    <menu>Welcome home! Tournedos Rossini!</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-21-2016</date>
    <menu>Chicken Pot Pie</menu>
  </day>
  <day>
    <date>01-22-2016</date>
    <menu>Chicken Pot Pie is one of our most delicious dishes.</menu>
  </day>
</weekdays>
XML;


$foods    = simplexml_load_string($foodsBuffer);
$weekdays = simplexml_load_string($weekdaysBuffer);

$names = $foods->xpath('/*/food//name');
$menus = $weekdays->xpath('/*/day/menu');

foreach ($names as $i => $name) {
    $pattern = sprintf('/%s/u', preg_quote($name));
    $result  = preg_grep($pattern, $menus);
    printf("%d.) %s: %d time(s)\n", $i + 1, $name, count($result));
}
```